# How to format the scrollbar in Kivy Listview

Tags: python, listview, scrollbar, kivy

I have a ListView containing customized buttons for the listitems. How can I format the scrollbar in such a way that it is always visible (in case there is something to scroll...), make it wider (10 pts instead of the default 2) and give it a different color?

The DoScroll.py file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.listview import ListItemButton

class ShowItems(BoxLayout):
    def get_list(self):
        self.results.item_strings = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"}

    def show_capital(self, capital):
        print capital

class CapitalButton(ListItemButton):
    pass

class DoScrollApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DoScrollApp().run()
```

And here is the DoScroll.kv file.

```
#: import DoScroll DoScroll
#: import ListAdapter kivy.adapters.listadapter.ListAdapter


<CapitalButton>:
    text_size: self.width - 50, None
    halign: 'left'
    valign: 'middle'
    font_size: 16
    on_press: app.root.show_capital(self.text)

ShowItems:

<ShowItems>:
    results: results_list
    orientation: "vertical"
    BoxLayout:
        height: "40dp"
        size_hint_y: None
        Button:
            text: "Get the list"
            on_press: root.get_list()
    ListView:
        id: results_list
        adapter:
            ListAdapter(data=[], args_converter=lambda row_index, 
                an_obj: {'text': an_obj,'size_hint_y': None,'height': 40}, cls=DoScroll.CapitalButton)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ListView` contains a `ScrollView`, which in turn holds the `GridView` holding the list items. The corresponding `kv` rules are these (from `listview.py`):

```
<ListView>:
    container: container
    ScrollView:
        pos: root.pos
        on_scroll_y: root._scroll(args[1])
        do_scroll_x: False
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            id: container
            size_hint_y: None
```

`ScrollView` has properties `bar_width`, `bar_color`, `bar_inactive_color`. These could be accessed through `lv.container.parent.bar_width` etc., for `lv = ListView()`.

Comment: Cool! Thanks very much. This really helps a lot.

Comment: Dear @zeeMonkeez, already a dated question but I would like to add a subquestion to this. Would it be possible to increase the bar_width on mouse_over? How could I get this event triggered when hitting the scrollbar with the mouse?

Comment: @BillBridge you may want to ask a new question. Haven’t used kivy in quite some time ...